# Cannot plot density plot with proper transparent option colours

Tags: plot, colors, histogram, density-plot

Somehow I cannot plot the color under the density distribution with the transparency option, as indicated in the `rgb()` function

```
d = mtcars$mpg
h = hist(d, breaks=10, col="blue", xlab="Miles per gallon",
         main="Histogram with normal curve", probability = T)
polygon(density(d), col =  rgb(1,0,0,0.5))
```

Which would be the problem to you?